# Sum of same elements from different arrays

Tags: javascript

I have a lot of arrays. I can list them together with for loops, however I need to show each element only one time if there are same elements in these different arrays. For example;

```
var array01 = [["Jack","92"],["Tom","74"],["Lily","100"],["Jonah","62"],["Lucy","83"]];
var array02 = [["Tom","94"],["Emma","70"],["Jack","100"],["Arnold","91"],["Kate","53"]];
var array03 = [["Jack","72"],["Tom","84"],["Emma","91"],["Jonah","92"],["Lucy","63"]];
var array04 = [["Emma","88"],["Marshall","82"],["Arnold","68"],["Ted","62"],["Lily","73"]];
var array05 = [["Jonah","87"],["Lucy","86"],["Kate","71"],["Jack","66"],["Lily","93"]];
```

I want to sort the results from the highest value to the lowest one like this:

Jack: 330
Lily: 266
Tom: 252
Emma: 249
Jonah: 241
Lucy: 232
Arnold: 159
Kate: 124
Marshall: 82
Ted: 62

Comment: what effort have you made to solving the problem?

Comment: I tried several ways to solve that problem. I looked at a lot of stackoverflow questions to find a similar way but i couldn't find anything. I've been trying to solve this problem for hours. Excuse my javascript level. I'm not an expert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `reduce` to sum the values by merging all of the arrays in to one, then apply `sort()` for sorting based on `score`:

```js
var array01 = [["Jack","92"],["Tom","74"],["Lily","100"],["Jonah","62"],["Lucy","83"]];
var array02 = [["Tom","94"],["Emma","70"],["Jack","100"],["Arnold","91"],["Kate","53"]];
var array03 = [["Jack","72"],["Tom","84"],["Emma","91"],["Jonah","92"],["Lucy","63"]];
var array04 = [["Emma","88"],["Marshall","82"],["Arnold","68"],["Ted","62"],["Lily","73"]];
var array05 = [["Jonah","87"],["Lucy","86"],["Kate","71"],["Jack","66"],["Lily","93"]];

var all=[...array01,...array02,...array03,...array04,...array05];

var result = Object.values(all.reduce((acc, [key, val])=>{
    acc[key] = acc[key] || {[key]:0};
    acc[key][key]+=+val;
    return acc;
},{})).sort((a,b)=>Object.values(b)[0]-Object.values(a)[0]);

console.log(result);
```